# Buttons not working properly

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclicklistener

In my main.xml I have 5 buttons all of which lead to different pages but when I launch the app  the buttons were their but when clicked they did not work. I think the problem may be in the AndroidManifest.xml

Menu.Java

```
package com.invoice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** called the activity is first created. */
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    }   
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO Auto-generate method stub
        //figure out which button was pressed
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //do button1 action
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //do button2 action
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            //do button3 action
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            //do button4 action
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            //do button5 action
            break;
        }


        }
    }
```

Android Manifest (only the button activity)

```
android:name=".menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.invoice.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    <activity android:name = ".Help" />
    <activity android:name = ".Job" />
    <activity android:name=".Fourm" />
    <activity android:name=".Receipt"/>
    <activity android:name=".Reportissue"/>
```

Job.java (same code is in every button java file)

```
package com.invoice;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Job extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.job);
    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:text="@string/report_issue"
        android:width="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="@string/help"
        android:width="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:text="@string/fourm"
        android:width="300dp" android:height="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/reciept"
        android:width="145dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
        android:height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/job"
        android:width="150dp" />

    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please provide stack trace for extracting more details what is happening exactly

Comment: Please post the button click code too. There might be problem in that part.

Comment: this looks ok ..please provide more details so that we can help you..and also provide xml for this screen...ans you can also use log for checking that onClick methode is getting called or not ..

Comment: I just added the requested code.

Comment: Your xml file name you have defined here is `Menu.xml` and in your java file you are using `main` layout file. Why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml file name you have defined here is `Menu.xml` and in your java file you are using `main` layout file. Why so ?

You should use the layout file `Menu.xml` in your java file. Just change the layout file name and then try to implement the onClick. It should work.

> ```
> public void onClick(View v) {
>     //TODO Auto-generate method stub
>     //figure out which button was pressed
>     switch (v.getId()) {
>     case R.id.button1:
>         //do button1 action
>        System.out.println("Button1 Clicked.");
>          break;
>      }
>    }
> ```

Comment: The reason the names are different are because of an error I made when naming the files, having a different named XML and Java file shouldn't affect it, should it?

Comment: Just let me know does your `main.xml` file contains all the buttons or not? Or you are trying to use the buttons of the `Menu.xml` file by inflating the layout `setContentView(R.layout.main);`?

Comment: The main.xml holds all of my buttons (there is actually no menu.xml that was a error on my part putting it in my question) Then the java (Menu.java) is linking all of the buttons. Sorry if i'm not making very much sense I am sort of new at it.

Comment: In that case your button click should work. Do you get any error in logcat ?

Comment: Try to print out something in your logcat. Check out i have updated my answer.

Comment: If the message is printed in your logcat then your button click is working fine.

Comment: That's the thing, Unless I'm running the logcat wrong there isn't any problems.

Comment: I think my logcat may have an issue. It doesn't show ANYTHING. Can you please tell me how to "print it in my logcat". Thank you very much for your help by the way.

Comment: You can print using ` System.out.println("Button1 Clicked.");` and also you can print the log as `Log.d("Button","Clicked Button 1");`

Comment: Use the toast message if you have issue with logcat `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: This is what I got when using the Toast method.

Comment: 01-27 23:53:19.268: D/memalloc(29619): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x552b9000 size:24248320 offset:24162304

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I figured out the problem was in the Manifest.

Comment: Please Mark any answer if anyone of have helped you for your issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Buttons are in `Menu.xml` File where as you are loding `R.Layout.main` 
and performing Button functionality there 
1st load the correct refrenced XMl in which buttons are defined then Run and if still have issues then share logcat trace here

Answer (score 0):

This what happens when you root your android.
Rooting is a great thing to do to your android phone because it will open up the features on your phone. However, it's very risky so I suggest if you are going to root, Root at your own risk!